# Gradle - Configuration to exclude modules from all "except"

Tags: gradle

I have the following configuration in my root **build.gradle** file:

```
subprojects {
  configuration {
    all {
      exclude module: 'slf4j-log4j12'
      exclude module: 'slf4j-log4j-impl'
    }
  }
}
```

I want the configuration applied for all sub-projects, except for one. Is there a way to disable the configuration just for one sub-project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select all but one like this . this should apply for all sub projects but the one you want .

```
//for all sub projects
subprojects {
    if (it.name != 'project name') {
        //do something
    }
}
```